# Alamofire - Extra Argument 'method' in call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i have searched about this error and i doesn't find useful.
Here's my code:-

```
   @IBAction func btnSave(_ sender:UIButton) {

    let teamName=txt1.text
    let memberCount = txt2.text

    let postParameters = "name="+teamName!+"&member="+memberCount!;
    Alamofire.request(URL_SAVE_TEAM,method:.post, parameters: postParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // URL response
            print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
    }
}
```

> Extra argument 'method' in call i am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pass this argument and it will work fine. Try this:

```
     let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

     manager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param,headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                if let value = response.result.value
                { }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `postParameters` variable like below:

```
let postParamaters = ["name" : "teamName", "member" : "memberCount"]
```